# How can we check if any 2 intervals of a unique ID overlaps?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have data of patient prescription of oral DM drugs, i.e. DPP4 and SU, and would like to find out if patients had taken the drugs concurrently (i.e. whether there are overlapping intervals for DPP4 and SU within the same patient `ID`).

**Sample data:**

```
  ID DRUG      START        END
1  1 DPP4 2020-01-01 2020-01-20
2  1 DPP4 2020-03-01 2020-04-01
3  1   SU 2020-03-15 2020-04-30
4  2   SU 2020-10-01 2020-10-31
5  2 DPP4 2020-12-01 2020-12-31
```

In the sample data above,

1. `ID == 1`, patient had DPP4 and SU concurrently from `2020-03-15` to `2020-04-01`.
2. `ID == 2`, patient had consumed both medications at separate intervals.

I thought of splitting the data into 2, one for DPP4 and another for SU. Then, do a full join, and compare each DPP4 interval with each SU interval. This may be okay for small data, but if a patient has like 5 rows for DPP4 and another 5 for SU, we will have 25 comparisons, which may not be efficient. Add that with 10000+ patients.

I am not sure how to do it.

**New data:**

Hope to have a new df that looks like this. *Or anything that is tidy.*

```
  ID    DRUG      START        END
1  1 DPP4-SU 2020-03-15 2020-04-01
2  2    <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

**Data Code:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), DRUG = c("DPP4", "DPP4", 
"SU", "SU", "DPP4"), START = structure(c(18262, 18322, 18336, 
18536, 18597), class = "Date"), END = structure(c(18281, 18353, 
18382, 18566, 18627), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df_new <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, DRUG = c("DPP4-SU", NA), START = structure(c(18336, 
NA), class = "Date"), END = structure(c(18353, NA), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

---

**Edit:**
I think from the sample data I gave, it may seem that there can only be 1 intersecting interval. But there may be more. So, I think this would be better data to illustrate.

```
structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), DRUG = c("DPP4", 
"DPP4", "SU", "SU", "DPP4", "DPP4", "DPP4"), START = structure(c(17004, 
17383, 17383, 17418, 17437, 17649, 17676), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), END = structure(c(17039, 17405, 17405, 17521, 17625, 
17669, 17711), class = c("IDate", "Date")), duration = c(35L, 
22L, 22L, 103L, 188L, 20L, 35L), INDEX = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you have only 2 drugs? Not more than 2?

Comment: Yes, 2 drugs only. But patients may have multiple prescription intervals for each drug. and each drug may have a different no. of prescriptions.

Comment: You can see my update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's way more complicated than dear @AnoushiravanR's but as an alternative you could try

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  full_join(x = ., y = ., by = "ID") %>% 
#  filter(DRUG.x != DRUG.y | START.x != START.y | END.x != END.y) %>% 
  filter(DRUG.x != DRUG.y) %>%
  group_by(ID, intersection = intersect(interval(START.x, END.x), interval(START.y, END.y))) %>% 
  drop_na(intersection) %>% 
  filter(START.x == first(START.x)) %>% 
  summarise(DRUG  = paste(DRUG.x, DRUG.y, sep = "-"),
            START = as_date(int_start(intersection)),
            END   = as_date(int_end(intersection)),
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(-intersection)
```

returning

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 4
     ID DRUG    START      END       
  <int> <chr>   <date>     <date>    
1     1 DPP4-SU 2020-03-15 2020-04-01
```

**Edit:** Changed the filter condition. The former one was flawed.

Comment: Thank you dear Martin, I think I'm missing something here but don't know what it could be! yours sound safer!

Comment: I'm thinking of "What happens, if the START and END dates of DPP4 don't overlap, but SU overlaps with both?". Or could the answer be generalized to more than two drugs? A larger dataset would be a good test scenario.

Comment: Yes I agree. It can be generalized to more than two drugs but about your first hypothesis I can't be certain until a larger data set is provided.

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, I tried to change the first lines before `group_by` to `df %>% split(., .$DRUG) %>% full_join(x = .$DPP4, y = .$SU, by = "ID")`

Answer (score 6):

**Updated Solution**
I have made considerable modifications based on the newly provided data set. This time I first created interval for each `START` and `END` pair and extract the intersecting period between them. As dear Martin nicely made use of them we could use `lubridate::int_start` and `lubridate::int_end` to extract the `START` and `END` date of each interval:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(START, END) %>%
  mutate(int = interval(START, END),
         is_over = c(NA, map2(int[-n()], int[-1], 
                              ~ intersect(.x, .y)))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(is_over)) %>% 
  select(-int) %>%
  filter(!is.na(is_over) | !is.na(lead(is_over))) %>%
  select(!c(START, END)) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(is.na(is_over))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(ID = first(ID), 
            DRUG = paste0(DRUG, collapse = "-"), 
            is_over = na.omit(is_over)) %>%
  mutate(START = int_start(is_over), 
         END = int_end(is_over)) %>%
  select(!is_over)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
    grp    ID DRUG    START               END                
  <int> <int> <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     1     1 DPP4-SU 2020-03-15 00:00:00 2020-04-01 00:00:00
```

**Second data set**:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    grp    ID DRUG    START               END                
  <int> <dbl> <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     1     3 DPP4-SU 2017-08-05 00:00:00 2017-08-27 00:00:00
2     2     3 SU-DPP4 2017-09-28 00:00:00 2017-12-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: Great answer, upvoted! To play it safe, I think it's better to arrange the rows by START and END in the ascending order first.

Comment: Thank you dear Thomas, I applied your very nice suggestion. Do you think I am missing something here? Maybe in a much larger data set a scenario I failed to take into account?

Comment: I think it's up to OP's needs :)

Comment: Yes let's see how it turns out. A nice base R solution would be a fantastic addition here :)

Comment: I added a base R option, but seems not fancy at all :P

Comment: It looks more robust than mine! I felt insecure after watching your solution haha

Comment: Thanks @AnoushiravanR, appreciate your answer. But, I think this works only if we assume that there is only 1 intersecting interval. i.e. I tried on this other sample data, `df <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), DRUG = c("DPP4", 
"DPP4", "SU", "SU", "DPP4", "DPP4", "DPP4"), START = structure(c(17004, 
17383, 17383, 17418, 17437, 17649, 17676), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), END = structure(c(17039, 17405, 17405, 17521, 17625, 
17669, 17711), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))` But it doesnt work

Comment: @HNSKD Please see my new solution for your new data set.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

As per updated `df`

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), DRUG = c(
  "DPP4",
  "DPP4", "SU", "SU", "DPP4", "DPP4", "DPP4"
), START = structure(c(
  17004,
  17383, 17383, 17418, 17437, 17649, 17676
), class = c(
  "IDate",
  "Date"
)), END = structure(c(
  17039, 17405, 17405, 17521, 17625,
  17669, 17711
), class = c("IDate", "Date")), duration = c(
  35L,
  22L, 22L, 103L, 188L, 20L, 35L
), INDEX = c(
  1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c(
  "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
))
```

we obtain

```
> dfnew
    ID    DRUG      start        end
3.3  3 DPP4-SU 2017-08-05 2017-08-27
3.7  3 SU-DPP4 2017-09-28 2017-12-21
```

---

A base R option (not as fancy as the answers by [@Anoushiravan R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709420/12158757) or [@Martin Gal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709604/12158757))

```
f <- function(d) {
  d <- d[with(d, order(START, END)), ]
  idx <- subset(
    data.frame(which((u <- with(d, outer(START, END, `<`))) & t(u), arr.ind = TRUE)),
    row > col
  )
  if (nrow(idx) == 0) {
    return(data.frame(ID = unique(d$ID), DRUG = NA, start = NA, end = NA))
  }
  with(
    d,
    do.call(rbind, 
    apply(
      idx,
      1,
      FUN = function(v) {
        data.frame(
          ID = ID[v["row"]],
          DRUG = paste0(DRUG[sort(unlist(v))], collapse = "-"),
          start = START[v["row"]],
          end = END[v["col"]]
        )
      }
    ))
  )
}

dfnew <- do.call(rbind, Map(f, split(df, ~ID)))
```

gives

```
> dfnew
  ID    DRUG      start        end
1  1 DPP4-SU 2020-03-15 2020-04-01
2  2    <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Upvoted all already, but why don't you try this in igraph?

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you. I have no idea how to solve it in `igraph`, since we need to find intersected date intervals. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Imho base R solutions are more fancy than using highly developed packages. +1

Comment: @MartinGal Thanks. Actually I need to learn those highly developed packages, I have very little knowledge about them

Comment: This is also great! My new solution has lost its fanciness :D

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Haha, my luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use a slightly different approach from the above answers, but this will give you results in format different than required.  Obviously, these can be `join`ed to get expected results.  You may try this

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), DRUG = c("DPP4",  "DPP4", "SU", "SU", "DPP4", "DPP4", "DPP4"), START = structure(c(17004,  17383, 17383, 17418, 17437, 17649, 17676), class = c("IDate",  "Date")), END = structure(c(17039, 17405, 17405, 17521, 17625,  17669, 17711), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA,  -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>      ID DRUG  START      END       
#>   <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>    
#> 1     3 DPP4  2016-07-22 2016-08-26
#> 2     3 DPP4  2017-08-05 2017-08-27
#> 3     3 SU    2017-08-05 2017-08-27
#> 4     3 SU    2017-09-09 2017-12-21
#> 5     3 DPP4  2017-09-28 2018-04-04
#> 6     3 DPP4  2018-04-28 2018-05-18
#> 7     3 DPP4  2018-05-25 2018-06-29
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(treatment_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(START, END), names_to = 'event', values_to = 'dates') %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = c('END', 'START'), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(dates, event, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(overlap = cumsum(ifelse(event == 'START', 1, -1))) %>%
  filter((overlap > 1 & event == 'START') | (overlap > 0 & event == 'END'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID DRUG  treatment_id event dates      overlap
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <int> <ord> <date>       <dbl>
#> 1     3 SU               3 START 2017-08-05       2
#> 2     3 DPP4             2 END   2017-08-27       1
#> 3     3 DPP4             5 START 2017-09-28       2
#> 4     3 SU               4 END   2017-12-21       1
```

---

on originally provided data

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID DRUG  treatment_id event dates      overlap
  <int> <chr>        <int> <ord> <date>       <dbl>
1     1 SU               3 START 2020-03-15       2
2     1 DPP4             2 END   2020-04-01       1
```

---

For transforming/getting results in original shape, you may filter overlapping rows

```r
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), DRUG = c("DPP4",  "DPP4", "SU", "SU", "DPP4", "DPP4", "DPP4"), START = structure(c(17004,  17383, 17383, 17418, 17437, 17649, 17676), class = c("IDate",  "Date")), END = structure(c(17039, 17405, 17405, 17521, 17625,  17669, 17711), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), row.names = c(NA,  -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



df_new %>%
  mutate(treatment_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(START, END), names_to = 'event', values_to = 'dates') %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = c('END', 'START'), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(dates, event, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(overlap = cumsum(ifelse(event == 'START', 1, -1))) %>%
  filter((overlap > 1 & event == 'START') | (overlap > 0 & event == 'END')) %>%
  left_join(df_new %>% mutate(treatment_id = row_number()), by = c('ID', 'DRUG', 'treatment_id'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID DRUG  treatment_id event dates      overlap START      END       
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <int> <ord> <date>       <dbl> <date>     <date>    
#> 1     3 SU               3 START 2017-08-05       2 2017-08-05 2017-08-27
#> 2     3 DPP4             2 END   2017-08-27       1 2017-08-05 2017-08-27
#> 3     3 DPP4             5 START 2017-09-28       2 2017-09-28 2018-04-04
#> 4     3 SU               4 END   2017-12-21       1 2017-09-09 2017-12-21
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantabulous! just merge the dates the way I did.